# php - extended classes carry objects

Tags: php, class, extend

I tried to ask this question earlyer but I think I rushed the question and did not get accross what I was thinking...

Does the value and objects of $this get passed to an extened class?

```
<?php

class bar {

    public function foo( $t ) {

        $this->foo = $t;

    }

}

class foo extends bar {

    public function bar () {

        return $this->foo;  

    }

}

$b = new bar();
$b->foo('bar');
$f = new foo();
echo $f->bar();

?>
```

if not, is there another decleration (instead of extends) that does without passing the object of the parent class to the child class?

regards,

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example would yield an `Undefined property: foo::$foo` error. I think what you're trying to use is a [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) property:

```
class bar {
    protected static $foo;
    public function foo ($t) {
        static::$foo = $t;
    }
}

class foo extends bar {
    public function bar () {
        return static::$foo;  
    }
}
```

Then the following:

```
$b = new bar();
$b->foo('bar');
$f = new foo();
echo $f->bar();
```

... would echo `bar`, which looks like what is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Phil: Slightly updated my answer. You may also want to check this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: @Phil: No, it is inherited from the parent class.